# Background process works but doesn't update data?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a background service which runs even when app is closed, it would get current location and once person is close to destination the app would start up.

```
package als.wakeup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Awake_Alarm extends Service implements LocationListener{
        Location location;
        ConversePrefs cp;
        ConversePrefs_sets cpss;
        LatLng final_dest;
        Settings sets;
        double final_range;
        LocationManager locationManager;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        final String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        cp = new ConversePrefs(this);
        cpss = new ConversePrefs_sets(this);
        sets = new Settings(this);
        final_range = cp.GetIntSetting("Range", 250);
        final_dest = cp.GetCoords();
        if(cpss.GetIntSetting(sets.def_units_name, 0) == 1){
            final_range = final_range * 1.09361;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("STATUS", "RUNNING");
    super.onCreate();
    }


    public double distanceGet(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
        double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
        double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
        double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2-lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        return 6366000 * c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        LatLng me = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        double dest = distanceGet(me, final_dest);
        if(dest <= final_range){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(dest)+" Away-.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("STATUS", "RUNNING-"+String.valueOf(dest));
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(dest)+" Away2-.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("STATUS", "RUNNING2-"+String.valueOf(dest));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

It seems to work fine, it launches etc and runs, and when location is changed it makes Toast text as required, but: The distance to target doesn't get updated, say I launch app, click start service and distance to destination is 1500 Meters, when location gets changed it still makes toast text saying: "1500 meters"

What am I doing wrong?